# How to use captured photo?

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I have the camera working in my app, but after the picture is captured and I select use, the app crashes.

How can I connect this use button and make it set a UIImageView I have created to the captured image?

EDIT

---

> Camera is available and ready
>   Using two-stage rotation animation.

```
To use the smoother single-stage animation, this application must remove two-stage method    
implementations.

Using two-stage rotation animation is not supported when rotating more than one view 
controller or view controllers not the window delegate


*** ERROR: FigCreateCGImageFromJPEG returned -12905. Input (null) was 658522 bytes.

Received memory warning. Level=1
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:         
'+[NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:]: method signature argument cannot be nil'
```

Thanks

Comment: If you could tell us why it crashes we could help. What do you see in the console or debugger?

Comment: I edited my question, sorry. I never posted the stack trace. these messages come from, me starting the camera, then taking a picture outputs the FigCreateCGImageFromJPEG as well as the memory warning and when I select the use button, the app terminates.

Comment: If I run it again it doesnt terminate but still gives a memory warning level 1. How can this be solved and also, where does one retrieve the image which is captured? I would like to set it to A UIImageView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Apple's [PhotoPicker sample project](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010196). From the description:

> The chosen image or camera photo is
>   displayed in a UIImageView.